# Should i need two different actions for two different request types

Tags: silex

I try to learn Silex. In my step today i would like to save a user over a registration form into my database.

In my first step i create a html form "register.html":

```
<form action="/register-user" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"  value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-success" value="Send" />
</form>
```

This form was rendered in my action "register":

```
$app->get('/register', function() use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('register.html', array());
    })->bind('register');
```

Now i post my form and i use another action to handle this post request, "register-user":

```
$app->post('/register-user', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
        var_dump($request->get('username'));
        return $app['twig']->render('register.html', array());
    })->bind('register-user');
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Can someone give me a hint or is this the right way to use two different actions?

**I solve my issue:**
I must use "match" instead of get and post.

```
$app->match('/register', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
});
```

Comment: Well, you don't need to use MATCH, you *can* use match but then in your controller function you need to check if it's POST or GET. IMHO is more clean to make the distinction in the route (defining 2 methods *get* and *post*), but that's very subjective :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use match() here. You can use POST and GET actions with the same resource '/register'. When the form is submitted the resource will receive a POST request, otherwise will be a GET and you can render the login form.

```
$app->get('/register', function() use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('register.html', array());
    })->bind('register_get');

$app->post('/register', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
        // process form information
    })->bind('register_post');
```